# Unknown white space appear on the right side of web page

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser, frontend

Here's the look:

[[image: Page with issue]]

I did the page in ReactJS, but I've made a copy of the page [here](http://codepen.io/flyfy1/pen/MKvRMy).

To better show the white space, here's the screenshot:
[image: Image Show White Space]

several interesting observations:

- when the page is first loaded, there's no such issue.
- the issue only appear, when the second image box (the one with 100% bar there) added into DOM
- `screen.width` = 375
- `$('html').width()` = 375, also
- I don't know how and why the white space appeared, nor can I find any element having width > 375. (I didn't check through all element though)
- `$('body').find('div').each(function(idx,e){if($(e).width() > 375) console.log($(e).width())})` would give me no output
- I try to do inspect on that white area, cannot. It would imply show me the body
- this issue appear both on web and on mobile
- this issue doesn't appear for the code in codepen I've shown above, although that code is an exact copy of the HTML generated (I copied directly from Chrome Inspector), with all the javascript removed

Any idea on: 1) why the white space appeared? 2) how could I solve the issue?

PS: just in case if you missed the part I put link to CodePen, [Here it is again](http://codepen.io/flyfy1/pen/MKvRMy).

Update 2: I have this input box which I'm placing outside the page:

```
<input type="file" class="attache-upload-button" data-reactid=".0.0.1.3.1.1.0.0.1">
```

Corresponding style:

```
.review-add-form form .uploader .attache-upload-area .attache-upload-button {
  position: fixed;
  top: -1000px;
}
```

Comment: i don't get where is the whitespace

Comment: @MattiaNocerino See the second picture on the right side, the huge white space is not supposed to be there

Comment: Don't just link to CodePen. External links rot. Put the [**minimum** necessary markup and styling](/help/mcve) **in** your question (ideally as a Stack Snippet, the `<>` toolbar button).

Comment: The only case in which I've seen this before is if you have an element that exceeds your width. Look for things with `overflow:hidden` set on them that could be masking the element. It might not be a single element that is wider than 375, but something that's narrower and hidden to the side.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Issue is I really don't know how to replicate this issue.. even an exact copy of the HTML code wouldn't result in the issue

Comment: @ingridly Yeah that's a hint. I have a input box outside. Let me update my question

Comment: `<svg class="bar">` if you inspect that element, you'll see that it's going "out of the document"

Comment: `.progress-bar-circle` try to add an `overflow-hidden` to that element and tell me what you got

Comment: @songyy: You need to include the markup and such in the question. Without it, we cannot help you. You clearly thought it was important enough to include it, you linked to CodePen. Twice.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder As I've mentioned in the question above, the link to CodePen is exactly a copy of the HTML markup I have in my current code. I'll assume this is `the markup and such in the question` you're looking for?

Comment: @MattiaNocerino You're great! The `svg` is actually the issue! How did u get the inspiration..?

Comment: @songyy: Re-read my first comment above. Emphasis: **in, not just linked**. SO questions are required to be self-contained.

Comment: Well when i have this kind of problems i usually inspect the whole document with chrome inspector... you gave me the inspiration to start from there because of your screenshot that was taken on the right of the svg.. so i started from there... pure luck? i guess

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I can see the point of doing that.. but when I try to paste in the code SO tells me that the length of my question cannot exceed 30k chars.. (but the code got 60k chars)

Comment: OK problem solved, within 15mins.. You guys are so quick in responses :) Thanks a lot for all the constructive comments :)

Comment: I was thinking to close the question.. but with the discussion in the comments area (and the answer below), I think the question might have its value for future reference

Comment: @songyy: Please read the [*How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example*](/help/mcve) page I linked above. There is a *reason* for going through the process of doing it. If you'd done that, you probably would have found the problem in a lot less than the hour you spent on it before then spending more time posting the question. "Reduce until the problem goes away and look at the last thing you removed" is a time-honored, fundamental debugging technique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I inspected the DOM with chrome inspector, and i saw that the `<svg class="bar">` is exceeding in width. I tried to set a `overflow: hidden` to the containing element, `.progress-bar-circle` and the whitespace disappeared

Comment: How did u saw that svg exceeding the width? Cuz I've debugged for 1h but unable to see that..

Comment: check the other comment in the question

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the CSS:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Faced this issue multiple times and in my case, it's generally a `div` or an `element` that is crossing the width of the screen thus stretching out, maybe try and analyze with chrome dev tools and inspect the layout, try and get rid of few divs and see if it changes anything, or maybe reduce the width of absolutely sized elements, etc.